# IONIC 2 Record 'Current Page' At Runtime And Come Back To This Page Later

Tags: ionic2

I have created an IONIC 2 application that contains many pages. It is a questionnaire application and each page is a question. This app works like a wizard: you answer a question and then click 'next', the next question will be presented to you and so on.

One thing I want to do is to record the current page at a certain time, then transfer back to this page at a later time.

My intuition is something like this could work:

To record the current active page:

```
const currentPage: any = this.navCtrl.getActive();
```

Then, I can pass the recorded 'current page' to other pages via NavParams. For example:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(AnotherPage, { 'originalPage': currentPage });
```

Then, I assume in the 'AnotherPage', I can:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.params.get('originalPage'));
```

However, it doesn't work. There is no error in developer console when I run this using 'ionic serve' in my web browser. However, then screen is blank. Just to be clear, I can see the 'AnotherPage' as from the original page to the another page is normal use of NavController. But when I request to transferred back from the 'another page' to the 'currentPage', it doesn't work (screen shows blank).

Any ideas of how to dynamically record the current active page and then pass it (or save it) somewhere and then come back to this page later?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found where I did it wrong....

**Wrong**:

```
const currentPage: any = this.navCtrl.getActive();
```

**Correct**:

```
const currentPage: any = this.navCtrl.getActive().component;
```

It works this time.